In SwiftUI, is it able to store function that returns view that is having Generic parameter?
I have this view
public struct DkTabScreen: View {
    public init(content: AnyView) { Content = content}
    let Content: AnyView
    public var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Screen Plug Template")
            Content
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding(6)
            .background(
                Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
            )
    }
}

And I like to store it in a Dictionary. It can be easily done as below
static var dkTabScreenDic: [String: ((String) -> DkListItem)] = [:]

However, If I change the AnyView to @ViewBuilder
public struct DkTabScreen<Content>: View where Content: View {
    public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) { contentView = content() }
    private let contentView: Content
    public var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Screen Plug Template")
            contentView
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding(6)
            .background(
                Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
            )
    }
}

I can no longer easily store it using
static var dkTabScreenDic: [String: (String, (String) -> DkTabScreen)] = [:]

It will complain Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred.
Is there a way to fix this, and able to store function that returns view that is having Generic parameter?

This sounds like an XY Problem. You should very rarely need to store Views, let alone in a dictionary. What is the bigger problem that you are trying to solve here?

There's no straight way to put generics of different (or unknown) type into one collection. But you can use a trick that is called type erasure which is basically creating a common interface for generic that doesn't have extra type information. It is used quite often, for instance you can have a look at AnyView.
Depending on what you want to do with the views one of the solutions can be to update the type of dkTabScreenDic and replace DkTabScreen with any View:
static var dkTabScreenDic: [String: (String, (String) -> any View)] = [:]

If you will need to access some properties of the views, then you can create a protocol like AnyDkTabScreen, conform all your views to it and use it in dkTabScreenDic but I would not recommend implicitly conveying info via swift ui views as it violates their responsibility.
protocol AnyDkTabScreen {
    var foo: Int { get }
}

static var dkTabScreenDic: [String: (String, (String) -> AnyDkTabScreen)] = [:]

